# Why can't I see my images in the website hosted in Github but seems fine in the repository?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, kramdown

Recently I started to develop a web page on Github and created a blog. Today while posting a book review, I found that I couldn't embed an image.
I am using kramdown syntax and using that I tried

```
![one-indian-girl](../css/images/oneindiangirl.png)
```

Then again I directly used

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="../css/images/oneindiangirl.png"/>
```

and

```
<img src="../css/images/oneindiangirl.png" alt="One-Indian-Girl" class="inline"/>
```

and all of these three appeared as **an image** the way I expected. However, when I opened my webpage, the first and third one appeared as only alt text and the second link was a broken image. I am not getting where I am going wrong. Any help will be very much appreciated.

The _post repository could be found [here](https://github.com/DarkDem/DarkDem.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2016-10-23-demi's-book-review-one-indian-girl.md)
and the corresponding website is [here](https://darkdem.github.io/2016/10/23/demi's-book-review-one-indian-girl.html)

Comment: As I found no luck with local call, I tried to put the direct link and it worked
`![one indian girl](http://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_800x600/HT/p2/2016/10/02/Pictures/_d8f2002e-8845-11e6-92b8-e7f1e026a3c4.png)` But I am still not sure why the other way its not working

Answer (score 1):

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="../css/images/oneindiangirl.png" data-pin-nopin="true">
```

here the `src="../css/images/oneindiangirl.png"` actually refereing 
`https://darkdem.github.io/2016/10/css/images/oneindiangirl.png`

address
however, the image is actually located in `https://github.com/DarkDem/DarkDem.github.io/blob/master/css/images/oneindiangirl.png`
or `https://darkdem.github.io/css/images/oneindiangirl.png`

so thats why image is not showing.

I am not sure about the solution though 
but you can try this

```
<img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/css/images/filename.jpg" alt="">
```

for your case it will be like

```
<img src="https://darkdem.github.io/css/images/oneindiangirl.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Well I did not understand. The source in every failed image is refering to the source which is `https://github.com/DarkDem/DarkDem.github.io/blob/master/css/images/oneindiangirl.png` if i click on the image showing in the post written with markdown.

Comment: However the solution worked as it is directly linking it. Still, I am not sure why the path hasn't passed. "+" 1 to your solution. but not accepting it as the solution for now.